Embeddings in time series prediction
Increasingly, I’ve noted that embeddings are used in pure prediction ML tasks. For example, instead of predicting whether user i will purchase item i and thereby adding thousands or millions of inputs to a ML model, embed both the user and the item by some external black box function then build a simple classification model which accepts user embeddings and item embeddings, which will be fixed in size over time.
Great! As for time series forecasting, I’ve noticed a lot of work in the single variable space such as Facebook’s prophet. However, it’s very common that we might need to forecast demand per region per product. A forecasting model that predicted t time steps into the future for r regions and p products would be computationally bloated, perhaps infeasible and not scalable as new products and regions are added to a business.
So I’m wondering what work has been done where a forecasting model accepts r region embeddings, p product embeddings, and t time steps (historic demand for the specific product in the specific region) producing q time steps predictions into the future?
I also understand that traditional forecasting methods, ARIMA, require de-trending data, which can be burdensome so DL approaches like RNN, GRU, LSTM and transformers are gaining popularity.
For this question, I’d like to see citations and holistic overview of time series models that accept embeddings and past observations such that predictions can be made for a wide variety of embedded units (products, regions, etc.)
What work has been done here and how is academia & industry trending?

I don't understand why an RNN can't do what you've asked, although I believe the max horizon has to be set during training. I believe this is referred to as "sequence-to-sequence".
